# PYTHON: How to convert Date/Time/Tz to Epoch in Python 2.7 with Standard Library

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, timezone, utc

I am scripting on a pfSense router box that is running python 2.7 and the standard library, as a result I don't have the modules pytz or dateutil to work with, and the strptime module doesn't support %z.

I need to convert date/times coming from another server (not local time) to a unix time stamp.

Is there a way I can insert the desired tz offset into a naive structured time and then convert it to GMT?

For Example consider the time 2016/08/14 02:15:10 [-0600/1] MDT coming from a remote server.  My TZ is EDT -0400.

If the value was from my time zone, I could easily do something like this:

```
>>> t=datetime.datetime(2016,8,14,2,15,10).timetuple()
>>> print(t)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2016, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=14, tm_hour=2, tm_min=15, tm_sec=10, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=227, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> ts=time.mktime(t)
>>> print(ts)
1471155310.0
```

I need some way to do the conversion that allows me to pass a time zone offest (I need something like: time.mktime(t,offset=-21600) but of course it doesn't exist)

I have hard coded everything because I can easily get values, it's the time manipulation logic I need help with.

---

I also tried the following approach:

In strptime %z does not work.

```
>>> time.strptime("20160814 021510 -0600","%Y%m%d %H%M%S %z")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 478, in _strptime_time
    return _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 324, in _strptime
    (bad_directive, format))
ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y%m%d %H%M%S %z'
```

Unless it is my time zone even %Z does not work.

```
>>> time.strptime("20160814 021510 MDT","%Y%m%d %H%M%S %Z")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 478, in _strptime_time
    return _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 332, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '20160814 021510 MDT' does not match format '%Y%m%d %H%M%S %Z'
```

but if on my time zone strptime DOES work:

```
>>> time.strptime("20160814 021510 EDT","%Y%m%d %H%M%S %Z")
time.struct_time(tm_year=2016, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=14, tm_hour=2, tm_min=15, tm_sec=10, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=227, tm_isdst=1)
```

Comment: Please be clearer.  What are the inputs you have and what is the output you are looking for?  Give examples.  Show some code of what you have tried.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that "epoch" is an English word meaning "the beginning of a period".  Your usage here is a common mistake.  You probably mean a "Unix Timestamp", which uses the Unix Epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z) as a basis.  The nomenclature "epoch timestamp" is nonsensical, because the only timestamp that is the epoch is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `%z` for numeric timezone is only supported from `python 3.x` here is a fix for python `2.7`

Instead of using:

```
datetime.strptime(t,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M %z')
```

use the `timedelta` to account for the timezone, like this:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
def dt_parse(t):
    ret = datetime.strptime(t[0:16],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')
    if t[18]=='+':
        ret+=timedelta(hours=int(t[19:22]),minutes=int(t[23:]))
    elif t[18]=='-':
        ret-=timedelta(hours=int(t[19:22]),minutes=int(t[23:]))
    return ret
```